# Remoting Appender log4net

Tags: .net, logging, log4net, log4net-appender

I am trying to create logging to my SOAP Webservice using a third party: log4net. My webmethods will be accessed by thousand users, so I need to create a way to log all messages received from them at the same time. in other words, i should enable multi process to log the same file.According to this link http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html, log4net.Appender.FileAppender MinimalLock implementation has issues while log4net.Appender.RemotingAppender can receive all the events and log them to a single log file by adding this to my web.config:

```
<appender name="RemotingAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RemotingAppender" >
    <sink value="tcp://localhost:8085/LoggingSink" />
    <lossy value="false" />
    <bufferSize value="95" />
    <onlyFixPartialEventData value="true" />
</appender>
```

But I am a little bit confused as it is the first time I'm using log4net, so my question is: What is a sink? Where can I view results? Any explanation about how this feature works would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Found these:

> Sinks are the objects that actually write the log to their target.
>   Each sink should be responsible for only single target (e.g file,
>   console, db)
>
> The following example shows how to configure the RemotingAppender to
>   deliver logging events to a specified Sink (in this example the sink
>   is tcp://localhost:8085/LoggingSink). In this example the events are
>   delivered in blocks of 95 events because of the BufferSize. No events
>   are discarded. The OnlyFixPartialEventData option allows the appender
>   to ignore certain logging event properties that can be very slow to
>   generate (e.g. the calling location information).

https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html

Comment: How can I view the results? where are the log messages displayed?

Comment: You would see them there where you configured them in your logging. This Sink is not a replacement for your log but a "buffer" .